# Adding a block to the layered category page

Tags: blocks, layered-navigation

I'm trying to add a block to a layered category page, and failing miserably.

Here is the layout I am trying:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/text" name="catalog.header" template="catalog/category/header.phtml">
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Can someone explain where I am going wrong please?

Comment: core/text does not allow any template I think

Comment: what block type should I use?

Comment: Block type core/template

Comment: first to add this as an answer gets the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block type definition should be **core/template**

As [Amasty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/12293/amasty) have pointed, core/text blocks doesn't allow templates